# How do I trigger a Combo Element?

Tags: infinity-blade-2

I'm fighting Ryth in Infinity Blade 2. When I do combos, most of the time I can hit that guy with hits where he loses about 120 health — the text then reads "Combo Hit".

But sometimes, my laser blade being equipped with an ice gem — I manage a "Combo Ice" and then Ryth loses 4000+ health points.

How is it determined when a Combo Ice, or more generally, a Combo Element, happens? Is it pure chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that sometimes, randomly, Ryth is vulnerable to one element. I was just getting lucky to find one of those times when I could hit it with 4000+ health points.

Answer (score 0):

If any weapon has an elemental gem attached or naturally has element damage every combo with that weapon should give combo "element name here".

On a side note, dual weapons are the funnest. Just go right>left>right>left (or the opposite direction, no difference) for nonstop combos. Really helpful with DoT elements like poison and I think Lightning/Electricity.

Comment: That's not correct, since Ryth is (most of the time) immune to all elemental attacks. See my answer.

Comment: I didn't notice you meant specifically against Ryth. You can see what elements any enemy has resistance to by hitting the 'i' button in the bottom right corner